# Syntax error in renaming columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename the columns below with the code also below but i keep getting a syntax error.

```
clean_data_dummies.rename(columns={'Indication_a-f': 'a-f', 'Indication_cva': 'cva','Indication_tia':'tia','Diabetes_yes':'Diabetes','IHD_yes':'IHD','Hypertension_yes':'Hypertension','Arrhythmia_yes':'Arrhythmia','History_yes','History','label_Risk':'Risk'},inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your dictionary, you should convert a `,` to `:` as shown below:

```
'History_yes':'History'
```

Most of IDE should highlight the syntax mistakes for you by default, hope you are able to find it